# data is not fetching from useLocation in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am creating a netflix clone like app and in here in my /youtube/movie component when i use useLOcation hook and fetch data from another component (./movielist)

it says "Property 'movie' does not exist on type 'Location'"

in my ./movie.js file so what i am doing wrong here and why i am unable to fetch data from uselocation hook

**./movie.js**

```
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./movie.css";
import { Publish } from "@material-ui/icons";

export default function Movie() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const movie = location.movie;
  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="productTitleContainer">
        <h1 className="productTitle">Movie</h1>
        <Link to="/newproduct">
          <button className="productAddButton">Create</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="productTop">
        <div className="productTopRight">
          <div className="productInfoTop">
            <img src={movie.img} alt="" className="productInfoImg" />
            <span className="productName">{movie.title}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="productInfoBottom">
            <div className="productInfoItem">
              <span className="productInfoKey">id:</span>
              <span className="productInfoValue">{movie._id}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="productInfoItem">
              <span className="productInfoKey">genre:</span>
              <span className="productInfoValue">{movie.genre}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="productInfoItem">
              <span className="productInfoKey">year:</span>
              <span className="productInfoValue">{movie.year}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="productInfoItem">
              <span className="productInfoKey">limit:</span>
              <span className="productInfoValue">{movie.limit}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="productBottom">
        <form className="productForm">
          <div className="productFormLeft">
            <label>Movie Title</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder={movie.title} />
            <label>Year</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder={movie.year} />
            <label>Genre</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder={movie.genre} />
            <label>Limit</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder={movie.limit} />
            <label>Trailer</label>
            <input type="file" placeholder={movie.trailer} />
            <label>Video</label>
            <input type="file" placeholder={movie.video} />
          </div>
          <div className="productFormRight">
            <div className="productUpload">
              <img
                src={movie.img}
                alt=""
                className="productUploadImg"
              />
              <label for="file">
                <Publish />
              </label>
              <input type="file" id="file" style={{ display: "none" }} />
            </div>
            <button className="productButton">Update</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**./movieList.js**

```
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
import { DeleteOutline } from "@material-ui/icons";
import "./movielist.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { deleteMovie, MoviesLogin } from "../../ContextAPI/MovieContext/ApiLoginCall";
import { MovieContext } from "../../ContextAPI/MovieContext/Auth";

export default function MovieList() {
  const { movies, dispatch } = useContext(MovieContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    MoviesLogin(dispatch);
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    deleteMovie(id, dispatch);
  };

  const columns = [
    { field: "_id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
    {
      field: "movie",
      headerName: "Movie",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <div className="productListItem">
            <img className="productListImg" src={params.row.img} alt="" />
            {params.row.title}
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
    { field: "genre", headerName: "Genre", width: 120 },
    { field: "year", headerName: "year", width: 120 },
    { field: "limit", headerName: "limit", width: 120 },
    { field: "isSeries", headerName: "isSeries", width: 120 },

    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Link
              to={{ pathname: "/movie/" + params.row._id, movie: params.row }}
            >
              <button className="productListEdit">Edit</button>
            </Link>
            <DeleteOutline
              className="productListDelete"
              onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row._id)}
            />
          </>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="productList">
      <DataGrid
        rows={movies}
        disableSelectionOnClick
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={8}
        checkboxSelection
        getRowId={(r) => r._id}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

code - https://github.com/priyanshu740/netflix-clone-mern

tutorial from where i am taking refrence - https://github.com/safak/youtube/blob/mern-netflix-app/admin/src/App.js(i am at 3 hr 26 min)

Comment: From `react-router-dom` documentation : `The useLocation hook returns the location object that represents the current URL. You can think about it like a useState that returns a new location whenever the URL changes.`
You might want to use `useParams` hook from `react-router-dom` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the data in the state property. so just do this:

```
 <Link to={{ pathname: "/movie/" + params.row._id, state: {movie: params.row} }}>
```

and where you are destructuring it out of location, just do this:

```
  const movie = location.state?.movie;
```

Comment: thanks mate it worked .....it means we have to create state object when pass a data from something to something when using uselocation ?

Comment: You can pass it with any property name, but if it's data that you want to persist for that route (as it probably is in your case), you should definitely pass it as state. so your code should practically work too (not sure why it's not right now), but the problem with it is you would lose the movie object if you navigate from your movie page to another page and then go back to the movie page again. react-router is looking for that state object and is persisting it for you. check this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-dawn-pfd8z where I show the problem I'm describing

Answer (score 0):

The way you're passing `to` prop into `Link` router component is alright.

In `movie` component you can use destructuring as follows for `history` object.

```
  const { location } = history;
  const { state } = location;
  const { movie } = state || {};
```